# Swift fixed sized array changes size after every append

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have created a fixed size array to collect user data from `textfields`. Each `textfield` is in a different cell. So I'm collecting all user answers in one fixed array

```
var userSelectionText = [String](repeating: "", count: 17)
```

What is really strange is that the array size gets enlarged with +1 every time I insert a string in a certain index in the array according to the row number of the cell.

```
self.userSelectionText.insert(diseaseSelectionArray[row], at: tappedTextFieldTag)
```

When I print out the array at first load of the view I have 17 items

```
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

After adding a string in a certain index of the fixed sized array I have 17 items + 1

```
["", "", "No", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Why? I need them fixed to reflect the exact number of rows in the `tableview`

Comment: There are no “fixed sized arrays” in Swift. You create an array with 17 elements. If you insert another element then it has 18 elements.

Comment: As @MartinR pointed out, there are no "fixed size arrays" supported yet. In the above code instead of using insert function you can use the subscript to replace the object. `userSelectionText[tappedTextFieldTag] = diseaseSelectionArray[row]`

Comment: May I suggest you read about [arrays](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107) in the Swift Programming Language book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're inserting (adding) elements into the array, but what you want is to replace the existing elements:

```
var array = ["", "", ""]
print(array)
print(array.count)
array.replaceSubrange(Range(0 ... 0), with: ["1"])
print(array)
print(array.count)
```

This outputs:

```
["", "", ""]
3
["1", "", ""]
3
```

Or, even shorter (thanks @Joakim Danielson):

```
array[0] = "1"
```

Comment: Why not `array[0] = "1"`

Comment: I went with the existing API use by inertia, I'll add your comment as well.